# New developer portal of azure API management is not responding in internal VNET mode

Tags: azure-api-management

We have several instance of APIM created a few months ago. Earlier this month we found a new developer portal. The new developer portal works fine for some of our APIM instance. However some of them have an internal VNET setup. So we configured custom domain for Gateway, New developer portal and Direct management. However, if I go the new developer portal it never loads correctly. It tries to access some endpoint of direct management and get request time out.

Comment: What exactly Is your question?

Comment: @TanveerBadar the question is what am I doing wrong? My expected behavior is our developer portal loads correctly even in internal VNET mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

> If your API Management service is in an internal VNet, your developer
>   portal is only accessible from within the network. The management
>   endpoint's host name must resolve to the internal VIP of the service
>   from the machine you use to access the portal's administrative
>   interface. Make sure the management endpoint is registered in the DNS.
>   In case of misconfiguration, you will see an error: `Unable to start the portal. See if settings are specified correctly in the configuration (...)`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-developer-portal#do-i-need-to-enable-additional-vnet-connectivity-for-the-new-managed-portal-dependencies